# NavigationView and ripple effect

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

I have designed a navigation view so as to understand how it works. I created all the fragments and I can navigate through the NavigationView. However,something strange happens. I will explain this with images:).

When I launch the app the home fragment appears. This is what I want.

[image: image 1]

Now I chose another menu from my navigation view.

[image: image 2]

Do you see what's happening? The ripple effect stays in Home menu. This is my menu xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item

        android:title="Home options">

<menu>
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:checked="true"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_hardware_keyboard_alt"

        ></item>
            <item
                android:checked="false"
                android:id="@+id/sub_one"
                android:title="Sub item 1" />
            <item

                android:checked="false"
                android:id="@+id/sub_two"
                android:title="Sub item 2" />


</group>

</menu>
    </item>
    <item

        android:title="Favourite options"


        >
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

            <item
                android:checked="false"
                android:id="@+id/favorite"
                android:title="Favorite"
                android:icon="@drawable/favorite"

                ></item>
            <item
                android:checked="false"
                android:id="@+id/sub_three"
                android:title="Sub item 3" />
            <item

                android:checked="false"
                android:id="@+id/sub_four"
                android:title="Sub item 4" />


        </group>

    </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings_applications"

        ></item>
</group>
```

Any ideas how to fix my problem?

Thanks Theo.

Comment: set android:checked="false" for Home menu which is currently true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your this code .

```
 <item
        android:checked="true"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_hardware_keyboard_alt"
```

change this

```
 android:checked="true"
```

to this

```
 android:checked="false"
```

You can set check `true` that's why `Home` menu is always display checked.

Comment: @Theo see my answer below.